# AwsElastiCache Redis cluster creation: CreateCacheCluster() vs CreateReplicationGroup()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Clusters.Create.API.html), to create an aws elasticache redis (cluster-enabled) cluster one must use the `ReplicationGroup
 createReplicationGroup(CreateReplicationGroupRequest request)` API and not the `CacheCluster createCacheCluster(CreateCacheClusterRequest request)`.
In the `createReplicationGroup` there is no parameter that specifies the `clusterId` but there is a field for `replicationGroupId`.

I have the following questions w.r.t the above context.

1. Will clusterId be same as replicationGroupId?
2. When I query the cluster information using `describeCacheClusters(DescribeCacheClustersRequest req)` will the cluster created using `createReplicationGroup` show up?

Answer (score 1):

Aws ElastiCache has essentially two kinds of clusters

1. Non-replicated cluster - Memcahed and Redis cluster-disabled with no replicas
2. Replicated cluster - Redis cluster-enabled and Redis cluster disabled with read replicas

To create non-replicated cluster you use `createCacheCluster` API and to create a replicated cluster you use `createReplicationGroup` API.

When a replicated cluster is created (eg. redis with 2 shard and 2 read-replicas-per-shard) a total of 6 `CacheClusters` are created and a replication group binds them together as a redis cluster. On the other hand if you create a Memcahced cluster with 10 nodes, only one CacheCluster is created.

So, if you query the cluster list using `describeCacheClusters` after creating the above mentioned configuration of Redis and Memcached you will get back 7 `CacheClusters` (1 - memcached and 6 - redis).

It would be better if there were more streamlined APIs to create the redis clusters without the users having to know about replication groups. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a single ElastiCache(say Redis) Cluster `createCacheCluster`. If you want to create a group of instances(Cluster) or Clusters you can use `createReplicationGroup`.

For your Other Questions.
1. Yes if the primary-cluster-id is not explicitly specified.
2. Yes if cacheClusterId is not given all the clusters are described.

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS documentation

**[CacheCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html)**

> The AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster type creates an Amazon ElastiCache
>   cache cluster.

**[ReplicationGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html)**

> The AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup resource creates an Amazon
>   ElastiCache Redis replication group. A replication group is a
>   collection of cache clusters, where one of the clusters is a primary
>   read-write cluster and the others are read-only replicas.

Basically the difference is if you want to have read replicas you should go with ReplicationGroup.